# Javafx TableView clear selection gives NullPointerException

Tags: javafx-8, changelistener

I'm having some problem clearing selection of the JavaFX TableView.
When I run myTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection() gives me following error.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.handleSelectedCellsListChangeEvent(TableView.java:2657)
at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(TableView.java:2180)
at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(TableView.java:1733)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(TableCellBehaviorBase.java:318)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehaviorBase.doSelect(TableCellBehaviorBase.java:231)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(TableCellBehaviorBase.java:144)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.access$200(GtkApplication.java:48)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$6$1.run(GtkApplication.java:149)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Does any one have this kind of error?
I made binding for the TableView and my Content.
TableView is showing content as I wanted. I wanted to select content from table view and process content then want to remove content from the table view.

My table selection Model listener is as follows:

```
orderTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            setIndex(orderTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        }
    });
```

Index is a IntegerProperty. I keep index in the integer property and listen for change.

```
index.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            Integer newVal = (Integer) newValue;
            System.out.println(String.format("Selected index changed: %s", newVal));

            orderTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();    
        }
    });
```

Here clearing section gives me above error. Need some help on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have had the exact same error.  I believe that it is due to the fact that you are modifying the selected index while you are inside of the `ChangeListener` for the selected index. If you look in the stack trace, it looks like you are hitting an event bubbling loop. So basically, you need to let the `ChangeListener` exit and let the other events for handling the selected index change before you modify the selected index again. To respond to the first answer from Zoltan, I too had this idea, but simple debugging shows that the custom `ChangeListener` is not getting invoked multiple times.

In my case, I was bringing up a dialog in my `ChangeListener` and then trying to clear the index when the dialog was closed. For me, wrapping the `dialog.show()` method in a `Platform.runLater()` method was enough to let all the events get processed first.

You may want to try wrapping your call to `clearSelection()` in a `Platform.runLater()` method. e.g.

```
Platform.runLater( ()-> {  orderTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();  });
```

Not sure if it will work, but it is worth a shot.

- chooks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the clearSelection invokes the changed method in your listener again and the newValue becomes null. You can try to put an if(newValue != null) statement there.